# SimpleSAML usando CakePHP - SimpleSAML_Error_NoState: NOSTATE

Tags: php, cakephp

Eu estou tentando configurar simpleSAMLphp usando CakePHP, no projeto usando apenas o PHP funciona tudo certo mas usando CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin recebi os erros quando tento acessar a View:

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to SamlAuthenticate::unauthenticated() must be an instance of Controller, instance of CakeRequest given, called in C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php on line 348 and defined [APP\Plugin\Saml\Controller\Component\Auth\SamlAuthenticate.php, line 49]
    Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to SamlComponent::login() must be an instance of mixed, none given, called in C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\app\Controller\UsersController.php on line 23 and defined [APP\Plugin\Saml\Controller\Component\SamlComponent.php, line 86]
    Notice (8): Undefined variable: url [APP\Plugin\Saml\Controller\Component\SamlComponent.php, line 87]
    Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple::login() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\app\Plugin\Saml\Controller\Component\SamlComponent.php on line 87 and defined [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php, line 100]
    Warning (2): array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php, line 102]
    Warning (2): array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php, line 108]
    Warning (2): array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php, line 110]
    Warning (2): array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple.php, line 120]
    Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:801) [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Utilities.php, line 585]
    Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:801) [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Utilities.php, line 588]
    Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\Alessandro\workspace\RW1\Projetos\Intranet\lib\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php:801) [C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Utilities.php, line 589]

Redirect   
You were redirected to: https://mysaml:9443/samlsso?...
```

E depois do login eu recebi o retorno:

```
SimpleSAML_Error_NoState: NOSTATE
Backtrace:
2 C:\xampp\simplesaml\lib\SimpleSAML\Auth\State.php:225 (SimpleSAML_Auth_State::loadState)
1 C:\xampp\simplesaml\modules\saml\www\sp\saml2-acs.php:63 (require)
0 C:\xampp\simplesaml\www\module.php:134 (N/A)
```

Estou usando o CakePHP (2.5.2) e simpleSAMLphp (1.13.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Link da resolução:** https://github.com/zl4bv/CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin/issues/7#issuecomment-63427478

Eu precisei mudar o tipo de sessão para 'sql' no arquivo `config/config.php`:

```
'store.type' => 'sql',
```

E tudo funcionou corretamente!